# How to Reuse getExternalStorageState?

Tags: android, class, sd-card

How can this be written in its own class to be used over and over again?  And where the comment line "//Loads the List" is, I need to be able to change that at runtime.

Thnx ahead of time for the info.

```
/**
 * -- Check to See if the SD Card is Mounted & Loads the Ordered List
 * ======================================================================
 **/
private void storageState() {
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

        orderASC();// Loads the list

    } else if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED)) {
        Alerts.sdCardMissing(this);
    }
}
```

REVISED:

```
class StorageStateChecker  {
  static void storageState(Activity param, Listener l) {
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

        l.orderASC_Label();//Load the list by Label ASC
        l.orderDSC_Label();
        l.orderASC_Title();//Load the list by Title ASC
        l.orderDSC_Title();

    } else if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED)) {

            // Pass context to AlertDialog.Builder
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(null).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("External Storage State");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Your SD-Card is not mounted!  If the device is plugged into a computer via the USB, please disconect the device.");
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //this.finish();
                }
            });
            // alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
            alertDialog.show();
    }
  }

public interface Listener {
    public void orderASC_Label();
    public void orderDSC_Label();
    public void orderASC_Title();
    public void orderDSC_Title();
  }
}
```

Comment: @LeffelMania / @Phil Lello Thnx for the input.  I'm trying to use Phil Lello's method (seems easier for this Java - Android newB).  Looking at the 'REVISION:' above, am I getting the right idea?  Also can you plz expand more on the call in an Activity with a more detailed example/code? I am not quite there yet - learning as I go.  Thank-you both. J

Comment: Plz see my profile 4 why I am here on SO. Thnx.

Comment: Looks reasonable, however `new AlertDialog.Builder(null).create();` needs to pass `param` where you've got `null`. I should also mention that if you could make StorageStateChecker a subclass of Activity, and have your activities inherit from that - I went for the static method/standalone class approach due to the somewhat vague description.

Comment: @Phil Lello  I'll give it a try 2morrow. Thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this:

```
public static boolean performExternalStorageOperation(Runnable doIfMounted) {
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

        orderASC();// Loads the list
        if(doIfMounted != null) {
            doIfMounted.run();
        }
        return true;
    } else if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED)) {
        Alerts.sdCardMissing(this);
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can replace the Runnable with any kind of generic Listener (I use OnClickListeners a lot for actions that aren't necessarily clicks) or write your own callback class with a common method to call, but that would be my general approach.

Comment: I'd also rename the method, storageState just sounds like a confusing name for this.

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds, and the Runnable solves the problem of not knowing what the mystery `this` is. +1

Comment: I absolutely agree with @Mike dg, that's a really ambiguous name for the method. It doesn't describe at all what the method does. I've renamed it in an edit. It's not perfect, but it's a bit more descriptive of what you're actually doing.

Comment: Plz see the following question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5902516/600984). I am using the first runnable when the Activity starts.  Then I will implement the other Runnable's with click-listeners.  I just cant figure out how to return my method(s) as runnable's.  Can you take a looksy?  Thnx for the above code.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a little trivial for it's own class, but one approach is:

```
class StorageStateChecker  {
  static void storageState(XXX param, Listener l) {
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        l.orderASC();// Loads the list

    } else if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED)) {
        Alerts.sdCardMissing(this);
    }
  }

  public interface Listener {
    public void orderASC();
  }
}
```

Note that `XXX param` needs replacing with whatever `this` represents in the call `Alerts.sdCardMissing(this)`; as Alerts isn't an Android SDK class, I could only guess.

To use the code, just call `StorageStateChecker(param /* was 'this' */, callbackClass /* implements StorageStateChecker.Listener */);`

Comment: Or use the [Runnable approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889385/how-to-reuse-getexternalstoragestate/5889516#5889516) from LeffelMania

Comment: See my Revisions & comments in my original Q. Thnx