# How do I Return a Runnable in this Method?

Tags: android, listview, return, sd-card, runnable

I don't know how to make a Return on a Runnable Method (or w/this particular method). I may have the idea wrong to(?). Any help? thnx!

*This is continued/related from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889385/how-to-reuse-getexternalstoragestate/5889516#5889516). But thought it could be a Q on its own.

In the Activities onCreate:

```
Runnable doIfMounted = orderASC_Label();
    StorageStateChecker.performExternalStorageOperation(doIfMounted );
```

The Runnable:

```
/**
 * -- Default List Order (Ascending)
 * =====================================================================
 * @return 
 **/
public Runnable orderASC_Label() {
    Cursor databaseCursor = db.rawQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM AC_list ORDER BY `label` ASC", null);

    Adapter_AC databaseListAdapter = new Adapter_AC(this,
            R.layout.list_item, databaseCursor, new String[] { "label",
                    "title", "description", "gotoURL" }, new int[] {
                    R.id.label, R.id.listTitle, R.id.caption, R.id.dummy });

    databaseListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    this.setListAdapter(databaseListAdapter);
    return /*null; <-- What do I do here to make this runnable */
}
```

The StorageStateChecker class:

```
public class StorageStateChecker {

public static boolean performExternalStorageOperation(Runnable doIfMounted) {
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

        if (doIfMounted != null) {
            doIfMounted.run();
        }
        return true;

    } else if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED)) {
         //Alerts.sdCardMissing(this);
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to use a method to return a Runnable. Simply declare a member (or static final) Runnable. All the code that executes goes in the `run()` method.

```
private static final Runnable ORDER_ASC = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Cursor databaseCursor = db.rawQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM AC_list ORDER BY `label` ASC", null);

        Adapter_AC databaseListAdapter = new Adapter_AC(this,
            R.layout.list_item, databaseCursor, new String[] { "label",
                    "title", "description", "gotoURL" }, new int[] {
                    R.id.label, R.id.listTitle, R.id.caption, R.id.dummy });

        databaseListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        this.setListAdapter(databaseListAdapter);
    }
};
```

Comment: I see.  Thnx! I'll give it a try.