# Pass a String to setContentView?

Tags: android, string, class, view

Is there a way to pass a string to 'setContentView()'?  ie: setContentView(OUTPUT).  The reason is that I have a class that I use for several activities (a custom ListView Adapter) and I need to use a different layout for one activity and would like not have a duplicate class where the only change is the setContentView().  I know that XML needs to be compiled in the APK but I am thinking that the inflation of the layout does not need to be in the onCreate...?  So, Can this be done using a variable?  Or does anyone have another idea/way of doing this?  Thnx.

*The Class I am using is [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5914823/600984) in the 'REVISED' code section.

Comment: i haven't tried it, but if you pass extras to the intent then do if extras indicate use layout1 {setContentview(layout1);} else {setcontentview(layout2);}?

Comment: @jkhouw1 That maybe a good idea - I'll give it a try 2morrow.  Thnx

Comment: it works, i just tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when starting calling your activity give it extras.  Then in your activity, test for those extras and call the appropriate setcontentview.

Answer (score 1):

setContentView() takes an integer paramter that is relevant to R.java, so, no you cannot pass a string to it.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [Resources.getIdentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to get resources by name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parametrize your activity some way:

- create an abstract activity class which takes `int layoutId` as constructor parameter, extend your activities from this class and pass different layouts
- pass layout id as parameter of starting `Intent`
- etc