# Android logcat error "getExternalStorageState/mnt/sdcard" when checking for external storage state

Tags: android, tabs, external, logcat, galaxy

On my Galaxy Tab 10.1 I get strange logcat errors when checking the external storage state with:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageState();
```

Logcat says:

```
03-10 14:13:22.700: E/Environment(32754): getExternalStorageState/mnt/sdcard
```

Did not really find something helpful when searching on Google. The only information I found that this maybe has something to do with the filesystem.

Can this error be fixed? I used API Level 11 in this small Test Project.

Edit: Just to clarify... getExternalStorageState() works and returns MEDIA_MOUNTED, I was just curious about this logcat error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5889516/1012284

Comment: bump.  I'm seeing this too, on a Galaxy Tab 10.1 and 8.9, and I'm not entirely convinced it's benign.  We see long-running HTTP downloads to external storage finish, but occasionally with a corrupted file, and methinks the two could be related...

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is just a debug log entry, not an error. I've seen error messages in logcat from my Galaxy Note that clearly do not mean errors.

You even can't find this message in the Android source code. It may be some debug messages added by the Samsung people.