# E/Environment(17152): getExternalStorageState/mnt/sdcard - Error in logcat but why?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-logcat, android-file

Hi i got this error in logcat:

```
04-27 10:16:12.160: E/Environment(17152): getExternalStorageState/mnt/sdcard
```

I just reach sdcard to save and load some images, everything works properly, no bugs, no crashes, i just get annoyed by logcat... Why is it marked as an 'E' - Error ?

Comment: see also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646773/android-logcat-error-getexternalstoragestate-mnt-sdcard-when-checking-for-exte)