# Default sdcard path in android

Tags: android

I'm having some problems with the path in my app.

A gallery of art asked me to make a video display that will show videos. So my idea was that they will only need to move the video file to sdcard default folder and rename the file to video.

But some cases (different tablets) the path does not match and the video will not open.

This is the code so far:

```
File sdcard = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(sdcard, "video.mp4");

String src = file.getAbsolutePath();
video.setVideoPath(src);
```

Comment: Any error messages, exceptions or specific symptoms you like to share with us?

Comment: I'a not an error, but in some tablets that I have here they just can't match the sdcard folder. Than they don't start the video.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if external media is useable with `getExternalStorageState()`. I think you'll need to see `MEDIA_MOUNTED` for your solution to work. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889385/how-to-reuse-getexternalstoragestate) shows a snippet with safety check. Might be a more foolproof solution to search all mounted media for the specific file name. That way, user can copy the video anywhere and your app can play it.

Comment: I'll try this MEDIA_MONT and will post soon. The screen is locked and the user can't close or stop the video, the action bar is hidden. It's a very simple app, I old them to use the default player, but they want the video in a loop and the video controller hidden.